# Controlling the network on the iphone simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, applescript

I am trying to debug a messaging bug between ejabberd and an iPhone and what I think is going on is some weirdness when the network drops or gets congested. I am using quickcheck to model the system and what I would like to do is have a way from a unix command line (via apple script) to turn the network on or off, or maybe adjust network speed.

Is there an easy way to do this (I am not an iOS dev)? I just need to be able to adjust the network

Comment: Take a look at this from our friends on stackexchange: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac

Comment: Thanks, have to figure out if I can adjust it from a script